# audio.buffered.end(0) throws error when replacing audio source

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I've built a simple audio player for my website using HTMLMediaElement (I'm avoiding the `<audio>` element due to personal reasons)

Everything seems to be working fine, however when I want to replace the source using `replaceAudio()`,  I get this error:

> Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'end' on 'TimeRanges': The index provided (0) is greater than or equal to the maximum bound (0).

Here's my code:

```
// ********************************************************************** //
// ****************************** Audio.js ****************************** //
// ********************************************************************** //

// Declare element and event listeners
audio = new Audio()

function replaceAudio() {
    audio.pause()
    audio.currentTime = 1;
    audio = new Audio('/static/users/' + trackUser + '/tracks/' + trackSlug + '.mp3');
    audio.load()
}
function addAudioEventListeners() {
    audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProperties, false)
    audio.addEventListener('ended', audioEnded, false)
}
// *** Declare minor functions

// Sets the progress or buffer width
...

// Converts the time integers to formatted time
...

// Get properties and update them

function updateProperties() {

    ...

    function getAudioProps() {
        ...
        buffered = audio.buffered


        // Return the values
        return {time:time,dur:dur}
    }

    var getAudioProps = getAudioProps();
    ...
    var bufferend = buffered.end(0) / dur

    ...
    setAudioIndicatorWidth(bufferend, bufferElement);

}

function audioEnded() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before start calling buffered.end(0) try check buffered.length first

if(buffered.length>0)
 // call buffered.end(0) / buffered.start(0)